# Launching Selenium test from bookmark?

Tags: selenium, bookmarks, launch

I have some Selenium IDE scripts for automating tasks (deploying to an internal server via it's web interface), and I want to have bookmarks to launch them.

Don't want go to Tools -> Selenium IDE -> search test -> launch test, just want to click a bookmark and let the script run.

How can I achieve this? Am I missing a point?

Don't know if it makes a difference, but I'm currently using Firefox (if I have to change browser for this, it wouldn't be a problem).

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Not sure whether you be able to run tests pressing on a bookmark as browser plugins are usually run with a key combo. And bookmark is URL. Well the main issue in your question how to associate bookmark
with browser addon launching.

Well, I've investigated a lil bit workaround. Speaking about getting Selenium HTML Test Suites Running Automatically (i mean an alternative to bookmarks) some solutions are possible:
**solution 1**:

1. Patch the Selenium server code to support HTML suites.
2. Build a script to execute your HTML test suites.
3. Build a script to read the suites’ output reports and consolidate
   the information for inclusion into your CC.NET report.

Setup details you can get [here](http://frazzleddad.blogspot.com/2009/02/getting-selenium-html-test-suites.html)

**Solution 2:**

- Selenium IDE plugin for Firefox to create tests
- Java to run Selenium Server
- Selenium Server to run test suites
- Nant to generate reports for CruiseControl.NET
- CruiseControl.Net as a continuous integration engine

Setup details [here](http://www.devbridge.com/articles/integrating-selenium-ide-tests-cruisecontrol-net/)

Hope this be useful for you.

Answer (score 1):

Bookmarks are nothing else than URLs, which makes it impossible to "bookmark" a functionality of a plugin, such as the Selenium IDE.

However, there might be other plugins out there that do what you want. I haven't had a closer look at it, but one candidate could be the [Favorites (Selenium IDE)](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/favorites-selenium-ide/) Firefox Add-on.

Comment: Am I wrong if I think that nothing prevents Selenium developers to make a kind of bookmarklet or something to achieve this? Or maybe a `chrome://` URL for loading saved test cases...

Comment: There seems to be an URL for the testrunner: chrome://selenium-ide/content/selenium/TestRunner.html, but probably that is not exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: not true; bookmarks can contain executable javascript code and even though their maximum size is limited to ~4K (browser-dependent) you can have a full-featured app packed into a bookmarklet, given that you can use js to bootstrap code from external resources; see also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookmarklet